# What if my javascript variable has the at-sign in its value in mvc3?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, email-validation

I have the following email-validator in my javascript, but the @ is getting misinterpreted in MVC3:

```
function validateEmail(emailAddress) {   
    var emailPattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/";
    return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Is there a way around this?  I've tried using slashes to escape the at sign, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to get rid of the quotes. Otherwise I see no problem with it.

```
function validateEmail(emailAddress) {   
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the quotes.  The @@ wasn't enough.  Thanks!

Comment: no problem, but just as an aside, I did test it and it seemed to work fine with only one @ symbol.

Comment: Your right, removing the quotes was the main problem; not double @@ needed.

Comment: just glad your problem got fixed. And thanks for marking as answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
function validateEmail(emailAddress) {   
    var emailPattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/";
    return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

@@ escapes @

Answer (score 5):

Escape it by using 2 `@@`:

```
var emailPattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/";
```